# XNA 4.0 storage framework not being recognized

Tags: xna-4.0, storage

This may be a silly question but, im unable to do any save game data because for some reason, this following namespace is unrecognizable:

```
 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;
```

All the normal XNA namespaces work but not this one. Im ade sure to uninstall XNA 3.1, and the windows phone 7 SDK. Then i un-installed XNA 4.0 and reinstalled it. Im not sure whats wrong, but i would really enjoy some help so could get to saving some games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for a Windows Phone project, you won't have access to that namespace. You'll want to use [System.IO.IsolatedStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.aspx) for Windows Phone applications. See [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604992.aspx) on how to do that.

Further, ensure your target framework and the project match. The project and the references need to be the same version. If you're using XNA 4.0, you need to have created an XNA 4.0 project. If the project was created as a 3.1, you can't use the 4.0 references.

Comment: its a windows game (4.0) application. Not sure whats wrong